# Configure filepath in dbt profiles.yml file

Tags: dbt

How can we read file-path as part of ssl_mode verfication in dbt.
I am trying with these keys(In Linux RHEL vm and usign postgresql database currently).

```
sslmode: require
sslcert: <file-path>
sslkey: <file-path>
sslrootcert: <file-path>
```

Currently I had tried with /home/user/cert_file But getting error

```
>Database Error
  FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
```

What is the right syntax for providig the file paths ?

Comment: What database are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Updated question, using postgresql for testing

Comment: can you share more of your redacted profile yaml? is the output what happens when you run `dbt debug`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried single-quoting the file path string?